# How to use real DB with SQLite in ABP framework?

Tags: c#, sqlite, asp.net-core, xunit, aspnetboilerplate

I'm using Xunit for writing test cases and using ABP framework which is built on top of Asp.Net Core 2.0. I want to connect to my local DB instead of memory DB so that I can verify the records while running test cases.

```
public static void Register(IIocManager iocManager)
{
    RegisterIdentity(iocManager);

    var builder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<MyCompanyDbContext>();

    var inMemorySqlite = new SqliteConnection("Data Source=:memory:");
    builder.UseSqlite(inMemorySqlite);

    inMemorySqlite.Open();

    iocManager.IocContainer.Register(
        Component
            .For<DbContextOptions<MyCompanyDbContext>>()
            .Instance(builder.Options)
            .LifestyleSingleton()
    );

    new MyCompanyDbContext(builder.Options).Database.EnsureCreated();
}
```

So to connect with my local DB I have made the below change, But its giving error. I'm using the same connection string in the application at other places and it works fine.

```
var inMemorySqlite = new SqliteConnection("Server=.\\SQLEXPRESS; Database=MyLocalDb; Trusted_Connection=True;");
```

Comment: What Error? Also that connection string is not a SQLite Connection string yet you try to use it with a new `SqliteConnection` object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to use a Non SQLite connection string with a `SqliteConnection` object.

If the intention is connect to an actual db then the connection string should refer to an actual db file

```
var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<MyCompanyDbContext>();
var connectionString = "Data Source=MyRealLocalDb.db"; //use actual path
optionsBuilder.UseSqlite(connectionString);

//...
```

Reference [Configuring a DbContext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/configuring-dbcontext)

Comment: I'm able to connect to DB, But it's giving an error that record already exists. But I can not see any entry in my SQL server DB table.

Comment: If it's not making entry in my DB, then where is it adding? and How can I see these entries? Does SQLite has its own DB?